# I have to remove HTML code that shows up on each page, where is it coming from?

Tags: theming

I am very inexperienced in Drupal.  I have been asked to remove commented HTML code that appears on each page of the website.  What file should I look for in the root directory to find the source of this?

The comment was added by another developer as a joke or something.  It's only wrapped in the body and appears close to the top.

The site is using Drupal 6.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! It would help if you show which HTML comment you are seeing, since we don't have access to the website in question.

Comment: I would post a link, but it's a school website.  I hope my edit gives more information.

Comment: Then just copy-paste the comment you are referring into the question.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably your theme files then, in /sites/all/themes/[selected theme]. You can also try to change the theme and check if it is gone.

Have a look at html.tpl.php and page.tpl.php files.

Comment: There are many places where a HTML comment can be added to the output. I would assume the theme is the first place where somebody would look for that, but I would not give that as granted.